# Is there anyway to get Jekyll to build automatically when files are re-written?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, jekyll, grunt-contrib-watch

I'm attempting to customize Bootstrap for an upcoming app I'm working on. I've cloned the [repo](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap), installed [Grunt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt) and [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/), and everything appears to be working correctly.

In order to see my changes I am making inside of the `/less` files, I have use the `grunt docs`command from the terminal because Jekyll doesn't pick up when `/dist/~` files are re-written.

Is there a way to get Jekyll to rebuild every time a file is re-written? Or perhaps a way to get Grunt to re-write the docs on every file change?

Answer (score 0):

`jekyll serve` will watch all files modification in the folder where you launch the command from.

Your bootstrap files **must** be in you jekyll folder to be watched.